# Static setVisible JFrame

Tags: java, swing, static, jframe

I'm trying to create a title screen for a game. Everything has gone fine thus far, except the fact that this JFrame refuses to close. I'm using a JButton in a different JPanel in a different JFrame. I get the error

> "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method
>   setVisible(boolean) from the type   Window"

```
package ZombieFunTimeGo;

import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SuperZombieFunTimeGo extends JFrame{

    private TitleScreen ts;
    boolean visible;

    public SuperZombieFunTimeGo() {
        add(new TitleScreen());
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(1280, 720);
        ts = new TitleScreen();
        Container pane = getContentPane();
        pane.add(ts);
        setContentPane(ts);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setTitle("Super Zombie Fun Time Go!");
        setResizable(false);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void pullThePlug() {
        WindowEvent wev = new WindowEvent(this, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING);
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemEventQueue().postEvent(wev);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SuperZombieFunTimeGo();
    }
}
```

Comment: *"I'm trying to create a title screen for a game."*  Use a [`SplashScreen`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/SplashScreen.html) instead.

Comment: What's the point of pullThePlug?  Just setVisibe(false). You need to make sure you are passing a valid reference of the title frame to the class responsible for closing it

Answer (score 1):

The error that you said is a compilation error, not a runtime error. You are not even able to compile the file. It seems that you are executing a previous compiled version of your code. Can you post the line where this error is being throw? If so, I can improve my answer. This error happens when you try to access some non-static member inside a static context, bacause you are not able to change an object state inside a static member, since static members belongs to the class, not to the objects. You are doing some strange things in your code... You added a TitleScreen to the JFrame, but after this you did it again (through the content pane) and set a TitleScreen as the content pane of the frame. It seems that you are new to Swing. Am I right?

Comment: Yup. This is basically the first thing I've attempted to write.

Comment: startButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
         {
             new theActualGame();
             SuperZombieFunTimeGo.setVisible(false);

         }
  });

Answer (score 1):

Right, the code you posted in your question is completely irrelevant. The code you posted in a comment is the one causing the problem

startButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
     new theActualGame();
     SuperZombieFunTimeGo.setVisible(false); } 
});

The problem is that you call the `setVisible` method as it were a [static method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) which is not the case. You should call that method only on a `SuperZombieFunTimeGo` *instance*. In this case your `ActionListener` will need a reference to that instance, and call `setVisible` on that instance. So something like

```
SuperZombieFunTimeGo titleScreen = ...;
...
startButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
     new theActualGame();
     titleScreen.setVisible(false); } 
});
```